# WCF Async methods failure because of bad network

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I am new into WCF stuff. I am curious to know two things about async methods:

1. What happens for some reason network goes down when I sending request to the service? Do I get any kind of exception or something k=like that?
2. What happens if network goes down when service tries to respond to the request? Does the result gets lost?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Sending a message through TCP (this includes HTTP) to WCF goes rougly through three phases:

1. Client sends message to the WCF service
2. Only when the entire message has been successfully received, it gets deserialized and its contents are passed to the appropriate service operation. The service operation runs to completion.
3. The response (i.e. what you return or throw from the service operation) gets sent to the client.

If the connection is lost during 1., your service won't see the message and your client will throw an exception.

If the connection is lost during 2., *I think* (but you can easily simulate that, for example using `Thread.Sleep()`) the service operation continues execution.

If the connection is lost during 3., the *response* will be lost, but the operation will have run.

Comment: Not directly, because a failed request will not end up in the WCF pipeline. If the connection is lost during the request, the _client_ will know it though and can act upon it.

Comment: I am sorry, I asked the question wrong. Is there way to know if sending the response back failed? Because the consumer depends on response from the service. Thanks.

Comment: @Dilshod The property [SendTimeout](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/explaination-of-different-timeout-types) is the timeout for both sending the message and waiting for the reply from the server, if the connection dies you just wait the length of time of `SendTimeout` and a `TimeoutException` will be raised at the line you where (a)waiting for the result.

Answer (score 2):

exception will be throw if the service did not respond. the program will receive the exception.
you can use try...catch block to catch it. then write to a log file if you want to record it.

Based on my experience, mostly the 1st connection takes time to initialize.
Sometime I get `EndpointNotFoundException` or `TimeoutException` if the service dint responds.

Therefore, i create a method to initialize the connection by passing message "connecting" to the service, if the connection established, service will return me a "connected" message. 
else if it return a exception , i will just let it retry.

I set the number of retry = 5. So it will loop for 5 time if the connection still not establish. Once establish , it will continue for next process.

we cant control the network connection and we cant expect and which point , which part it fail. 
but we can control our program when the service failed. Depends on what you want to do if the service failed. maybe clean the data, restart the process or stop the program immediately and log the error for investigation.

Comment: this is very handy thanks. Do you have any other tips for using WCF over poor connections? Have you experimented with breaking up data in different ways, different protocols or bindings, etc? Did you compare with using raw TCP? I'm writing a system for communicating over rural Ethiopia's very patchy connection.